# Is there any way to save a pandas dataframe to hive table？

Tags: pandas, hive

I have create a table in hive by using HQL and need insert a dataframe to it.
Is there anyway to do this? like using `pd.to_sql()` method for mysql. 
Now, i am using `pd.to_csv()` get a csv file and load it to hive.

Thanks

Comment: yes check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql)

Comment: @JiaJie999, did you find the solution to make it work ?

Comment: One solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817958/pandas-dataframe-to-hive-table